# scanf crashes program and comparing string C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, equality, strcmp

I'm a beginner in C, and got a crash of my program when it gets to the end.

It is a mini game in which the user have to guess a number. When it's found, the program asks the user if he wants to play a new game.

Please find my code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
int MAX = 100, MIN = 0;
int nombreCoup = 0;
int nombreMystere = 0;
int nombreJoueur;
char newPartie;
int continuerPartie = 0;
int niveauDiffic;

srand(time(NULL));
nombreMystere = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;

printf("Bonjour, ceci est un mini jeu dans lequel vous allez devoir deviner un nombre choisi aleatoirement entre 0 et 100.:\n");

while (continuerPartie = 1)
{

    printf("Choisissez votre niveau de difficulte entre 1 et 3 :\n");
    scanf("%d", &niveauDiffic);

    switch (niveauDiffic)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Vous avez selectionne la difficulte Facile. Le jeu commence.\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Vous avez selectionne la difficulte Normale. Le jeu commence.\n");
            niveauDiffic = 2;
            MAX = 1000;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Vous avez selectionne la difficulte Difficile. Le jeu commence.\n");
            niveauDiffic = 3;
            MAX = 10000;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Mauvaise entrée, la difficulte sera donc reglee sur Facile. \n");
            break;          
    }


    printf ("\n On y va : \n");
    scanf ("%d", &nombreJoueur);
    nombreCoup++;

    do {
        if (nombreJoueur > nombreMystere) {
            printf ("Le nombre mystere est plus petit !\n");
            nombreCoup = nombreCoup + 1 ;
            printf("Retente ta chance !  \n \n");
            scanf ("%d", &nombreJoueur);
        }

        else {
            printf ("Le nombre mystere est plus grand ! \n");
            nombreCoup = nombreCoup + 1 ;
            printf("Retente ta chance ! \n \n");
            scanf ("%d", &nombreJoueur);    
        }


    } while (nombreJoueur != nombreMystere);

    printf ("Vous avez trouver le nombre mystere en %d coups ! \nVoulez vous rejouer ? (Y/N)  ", nombreCoup);
    scanf("%1c", &newPartie);
    printf ("%c", newPartie);

    if (strcmp(newPartie, "Y" == 0)|| strcmp(newPartie, "y" == 0))
    {
        printf ("Et c'est reparti !!'");
        }

    else    {
        continuerPartie = 0;
        }

}
return 0;   
}
```

The problem is that the program crashes at the last `scanf()`. I also got this warning while compiling :

> "passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast"

but I didn't manage to get rid of it.

EDIT :

Thanks for your help guyz, looks like I have to get more focused on my syntax... Now my code is not crashing, I've applied the corrections. The only remaining problem is that this code :

```
    printf ("Vous avez trouver le nombre mystere en %d coups ! \nVoulez vous rejouer ? (Y/N)  ", nombreCoup);
scanf("%1c", &newPartie);
printf ("%c", newPartie);

if ((newPartie == 'Y') || newPartie == 'y')
{
    printf ("Et c'est reparti !!'");
    }

else    {
    continuerPartie = 0;
    }
```

Is not executed... I don't know why but it closes after last printf before the if..

EDIT 2 :

Here is the solution, thanks to @Sourav Gosh

Did you try scanf(" %1c", &newPartie);?, **mind the space before %**. –  Sourav Ghosh.

Comment: `newPartie` is a `char`.Use `if (newPartie == 'Y') || newPartie == 'y')` instead of `if (strcmp(newPartie, "Y" == 0)|| strcmp(newPartie, "y" == 0))`. `strcmp` requires both its arguments to be of type `char*` and both needs to be NUL-terminated. Also, use`while (continuerPartie == 1)` instead of `while (continuerPartie = 1)`.The former compares `continuerPartie` with 1 while the latter assigns 1 to it(which makes it an infinite loop as 1 is a non-zero number and all non-zero numbers are considered to be true) and change `int continuerPartie = 0;` to `int continuerPartie = 1;` to make loop run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1**

In your code,

```
while (continuerPartie = 1)
```

is not doing what you think it's doing. Maybe you wanted to use the **equality operator** (`==`) instead. Otherwise, it's an infinite loop.

That said, you should be initializing `continuerPartie` to `1` isntead of `0` to ensure the `while()` loop is satified in the first iteration.

**Point 2**

```
strcmp(newPartie, "Y" == 0)
```

is not the proper use.

Either use

- `strncmp()` with `&newPartie` and `n` as `1`, or (*not a very good approach*)
- (*better*) use simple equality operator `==` like  `if ((newPartie=='Y')|| (newPartie=='y'))`

Also, the `==` equality comparison in `strcmp()`/`strncmp()` should look like `strncmp(a,b,c) == 0`

**Point 3**

Change

```
  scanf("%1c", &newPartie);
```

to

```
 scanf(" %1c", &newPartie);
```

to ignore the previous *newline* stored in the input buffer and *scan* the non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your program:

```
while (continuerPartie = 1)
```

It continually assigns `continuerPartie` the value of 1.

Change it to:

```
while (continuerPartie == 1)
```

Also, `newPartie` is a char, not string.

```
    if (strcmp(newPartie, "Y" == 0)|| strcmp(newPartie, "y" == 0))
```

should be:

```
   if ((newPartie=='Y')|| (newPartie=='y'))
```